# Error with javacc generated AST files

Tags: compiler-errors, abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

My program Lang.jtt is auto generating AST java files. I am able to compile the jjt file, then the generated .jj file but when I enter javac *.java I am getting errors with the automatically generated  AST files. I'm not sure what's causing this as it is occurring for every implementation of an ASTfor me. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

The errors I'm getting are as follows:

> ASTall_op.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTall_op(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTall_op(ASTall_op,Object)   location: variable visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTProg.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTProg(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTProg(ASTProg,Object)   location: variable visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTprogram.java:16:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTprogram(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTprogram(ASTprogram,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTdecl_list.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTdecl_list(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTdecl_list(ASTdecl_list,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTdecl.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTdecl(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTdecl(ASTdecl,Object)   location: variable visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTvar_decl.java:16:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTvar_decl(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTvar_decl(ASTvar_decl,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTconst_decl.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTconst_decl(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTconst_decl(ASTconst_decl,Object)   location: variable visitor
>   of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTfunction_list.java:16: error: cannot find
>   symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTfunction_list(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTfunction_list(ASTfunction_list,Object)   location: variable
>   visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTfunction.java:16: error: cannot find
>   symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTfunction(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTfunction(ASTfunction,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTtype.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTtype(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTtype(ASTtype,Object)   location: variable visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTparameter_list.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTparameter_list(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTparameter_list(ASTparameter_list,Object)   location: variable
>   visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTnemp_parameter_list.java:16: error:
>   cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTnemp_parameter_list(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTnemp_parameter_list(ASTnemp_parameter_list,Object)   location:
>   variable visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTmain.java:16: error: cannot
>   find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTmain(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTmain(ASTmain,Object)   location: variable visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTstatement_block.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTstatement_block(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTstatement_block(ASTstatement_block,Object)   location:
>   variable visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTstatement.java:16: error:
>   cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTstatement(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTstatement(ASTstatement,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTcondition.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTcondition(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTcondition(ASTcondition,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTexpression.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTexpression(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTexpression(ASTexpression,Object)   location: variable visitor
>   of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTfragment.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTfragment(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTfragment(ASTfragment,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTboolean_op.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTboolean_op(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTboolean_op(ASTboolean_op,Object)   location: variable visitor
>   of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTcomp_op.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTcomp_op(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTcomp_op(ASTcomp_op,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTbinary_arith_op.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTbinary_arith_op(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTbinary_arith_op(ASTbinary_arith_op,Object)   location:
>   variable visitor of type LangVisitor
>
> ASTarg_list.java:16: error:
>   cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTarg_list(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTarg_list(ASTarg_list,Object)   location: variable visitor of
>   type LangVisitor
>
> ASTnemp_arg_list.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>       return visitor.visitASTnemp_arg_list(this, data);
>                     ^   symbol:   method visitASTnemp_arg_list(ASTnemp_arg_list,Object)   location: variable
>
> visitor of type LangVisitor 23 errors

Comment: What options are used in the .jjt file?

Comment: The issue was due to my installation of Javacc it wasn't working. I solved this by installing an earlier version